# Apache 2.4 replies with "403 Forbidden" for a CGI script, my configuration looks ok

Tags: perl, apache-2.4, cgi, mod-auth

I installed a CGI script on a fresh installation of Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu server 14.04. **Apache keeps replying with *403 Forbidden*** also if, to me, the configuration file is ok. The CGI is the Monitorix front-end, a system monitoring tool written in Perl.

The configuration file `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/monitorix.conf` is:

```
Alias /monitorix /var/lib/monitorix/www
ScriptAlias /monitorix-cgi /var/lib/monitorix/www/cgi

<Directory /var/lib/monitorix/www/cgi/>
        DirectoryIndex monitorix.cgi
        Options ExecCGI
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
                # Apache 2.4
                Require all granted
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
                # Apache 2.2
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

All files in `/var/lib/monitorix/www` and `/var/lib/monitorix/www/cgi` have at least read permission for all. Every time I try to access from URL `/monitorix`, in my Apache log I see lines:

```
[Mon Sep 01 06:57:52.995680 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 17145] [client x.x.x.x:58879] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/lib/monitorix/www
[Mon Sep 01 07:00:10.131166 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 17145] [client x.x.x.x:58903] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/lib/monitorix/www
[Mon Sep 01 07:00:11.102614 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 17145] [client x.x.x.x:58903] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/lib/monitorix/www
...
```

Plus, I cannot get why, when I try to access from URL `/monitorix-cgi` (I got the idea from the `ScriptAlias` directive) I get *200 Ok* and **I can see the Perl source** of `/var/lib/monitorix/www/cgi/monitorix.cgi`.

Time ago I installed this tool on Debian and I had no problems, `/monitorix` worked as expected and `/monitorix-cgi` correctly gave me *403 Forbidden* instead of showing the Perl source file.

**Update**: this issue has been reported to Monitorix and probably [fixed (#69)](https://github.com/mikaku/Monitorix/issues/69)

Comment: What is in your logs?

Comment: @PeterHorvath What logs? I posted the Apache error log. In `/var/log/monitorix*` there are many files, but no line is added when trying to connect, and I can't see errors. I'm not a Perl developer, I do not know if there are logs somewhere else...

Comment: are you using a WAF (Web Application Firewall) ?

Comment: @thanasisk I don't think so, except if something came preinstalled with Ubuntu 14.04 Server or Apache 2.4. I only checked for `mod_security` and it's not installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you access /monitorix in a browser, you are accessing /var/lib/monitorix/www.  Your Directory block allows access to /var/lib/monitorix/www/***cgi***, not /var/lib/monitorix/www.  Either change the Alias to:

```
Alias /monitorix /var/lib/monitorix/www/cgi
```

or add an additional Directory block:

```
<Directory /var/lib/monitorix/www/>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            # Apache 2.4
            Require all granted
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            # Apache 2.2
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

As for seeing the source of the cgi, it's probably mod_cgi's configuration.  Either it's not enabled or it's not set to handle *.cgi files.  You may need to add:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
```

to your virtualhost or directory block.  If that doesn't work, try this in your shell:

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
```

and follow the instructions to reload apache.  If it still doesn't work, add a comment below and possibly update your question.  I'll take another look and maybe set up a test system.

Comment: Great! I needed to enable `cgi` module **and** add the second `Directory` block. Changing the `Alias` as you suggested made the app *half-working*: I think it uses some files from `www/` and scripts from `/www/cgi`, so... [Here is the entire working config file](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=8diQS7qK)

Comment: You can keep the alias you had, you just needed to allow it with a directory block.  Sounds like you should change the alias back and keep the new directory block.  - ok, good, looks like you did that already.

Comment: If you want to clean it up a bit, you only need the IfModule directives in the /www level directory block.  /www/cgi will inherit them.

Comment: Yep! I will award the bounty ASAP (23h left). Thank you very much Jeff!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a Require line:

```
Require all granted
```

Comment: It's there, I wrote all my config in my question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

The following config worked for me (Apache 2.4):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>                                                                                                                                                                                        
        ServerName your.server.com                                                                                                                                                                      
        DocumentRoot "/var/lib/monitorix/www"                                                                                                                                                              

        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi                                                                                                                                                                         

        Alias /cgi /var/lib/monitorix/www/cgi                                                                                                                                                              

        <Directory "/var/lib/monitorix/www">                                                                                                                                                               
                Require all granted                                                                                                                                                                        
        </Directory>                                                                                                                                                                                       

        <Directory "/var/lib/monitorix/www/cgi">                                                                                                                                                           
                AllowOverride None                                                                                                                                                                         
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch                                                                                                                                         
                Require all granted                                                                                                                                                                        
        </Directory>                                                                                                                                                                                       
</VirtualHost>
```

The /etc/monitorix/monitorix.conf, looks like:

```
    base_url = /                                                                                                                                                                                               
    base_cgi = /cgi
```

And disable the build-in httpd service:

```
<httpd_builtin>                                                                                                                                                                                        
            enabled = n
```